# Evaluate integral $ \ \ \int_{ 0 } ^{ 1 } f(x)dx $

Tags: probability

Suppose that the random variable X represents the grade (measured as a percentage from $ 0 \ \ to \ \ 1 \ $) of a person chosen at random, and  $ f(x) \ $ is the probability density function for $ X. $ Then

a) Evaluate integral $ \ \ \int_{ 0 } ^{ 1 } f(x)dx $

**Ans:**

My question  is , since the random variable is continuous on $  \ [0,1] \ $ ( my view) and the density function is not given , **how can I find the integral ?**

**Is there any idea ?**

Comment: Hint: all the probabilities in a sample space sum to...

Comment: Also, the random variable need not be continuous for the integral to be known over its support. Check your axioms.

Comment: how to evaluate the sum ?  any help

Comment: The whole point is that the integral of a probability density function, between a and b, is the probability that the variable lies between a and b.  Here, the percentages can only be between 0 and 1 so the integral from 0 to 1 must be 1.

Comment: In this case, you do not need to know the exact density $f(x)$. The integral $\int_a^b f(x) dx$ is the probability that a random person's grade is in the range  $a \leq x \leq b$. In this case, what is the probability that a person's grade is in the range $0 \leq x \leq 1$ ?

Comment: what would be the probability that the person gets  grade $ \ \frac{1}{4} \ $ ?

Comment: @mabmath The probability that the grade is exactly 1/4 is $\int_{1/4}^{1/4} f(x) \,dx = 0$ (because you have a density function the RV is (absolutely) continuous). The probability that the grade is at least 1/4 is $\int_{1/4}^{\infty} f(x) \,dx = \int_{1/4}^1 f(x)\,dx$ (since the support of $X$ is $[0,1]$, one can put the upper bound as $1$).